# Creating auto-scaling Qt UI using Layouts

Tags: qt, user-interface, qlayout

I'd appreciate advise on to how create a Qt UI consisting of four layouts and has the following properties.

1. Any increases in the height of the UI is absorbed by the layouts, as shown below
   [image]
2. Any further decreases in the height of the UI is absorbed by the contents of a specific layout, e.g. the two large buttons as shown below
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prepared quick code what fits your problem, please take a look: https://github.com/troyane/StackOverflow-pro/tree/master/creating-auto-scaling-qt-ui-using-layouts

Grab that code and take a look at next moments (you can open `mainwindow.ui` in QtCreator):

- `centralWidget` has next `layoutStretch` param: `1,2,1,1` -- it means, that we'll have next correlation among all items placed into this vertical layout.
- `TextLabel` and both `SmallButton`s has `Fixed` VerticalPolicy
- Both `BigButton`s has `Minimum` vertical policy and set minimumSize's Height to 100. **UPD:** Also `maximumSize`->`height` parameter is `250` px. So, it is guarantee that both BigButtons will not grow more than 250 px on height.

Take a look at [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25575113/867349), there you can find lots of literature to read about **Layouts**.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I don't want the Big Buttons to grow beyond an extent. Is there a way to clamp the height of the big buttons to a maximum value?

Comment: Of course, see updated answer and updated code in repo.

Answer (score 8):

1# Create new UI form base on QWidget: File -> New file or project -> Qt -> Qt Designer form class -> select Widget form templates, next, next, select project and finish

2# Add Vertical layout from left bar

[image]

3# After that click right somewhere on UI form, where is not just added layout, "Lay out" -> "Lay out in a grid"

[image]

4# You can adjust layout margin on right menu (I'm always setting 5 points)

5# Add four Horizontal layout

[image]

6# Add Button and text and what you need

[image]

7# Add Vertical spacers between Horizontal layout

[image]

8# Final result:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can put two vertical spacers in each layout. One should be placed at top most and the other one at the bottom :

[image]